# React Native can not using Spread Operator to update object in array

Tags: react-native, operators

i have the state that control the flatList data

const [data, setData] = useState([])

i have a object like below(after get from network, it's show success in FlatList)

```
data = [{
  'name' : 1,
 },
 {'name' : 2,
 }]
```

Now i want to update first object ***{'name': 1}*** by add some key/value like this:

```
{ 'name' : 1, 'text' : 'this is text'}
```

Here is my code:

```
const mathched = data[0]
mathched = [
              ...mathched,
              {'text': 'this is text'}
            ]
```

But i got error: ***TypeError: "mathched" is read-only***

I tried other solution by set new key to object:

```
const newData = [...data]
const mathched = newData[0]
mathched['text'] = 'this is text'
setData(newData)
```

But data not changed

Can someone guide me how to use Speard Operator to done my solution? Thanks

Comment: Where in the component you are trying to update the first element of the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the state value is a read-only variable that can be modified only via the setter, setData in this case.

When you do const matched = data[0] then matched = newData[0] you are attempting to store the new value without the setter usage.

One way to go would be:

```
// Usign for example Lodash clone
const newClonedData = clone(data);
newClonedData[0] = { ...matched[0], {'text': 'this is text'} };
setData[newClonedData];
```